# Slow execution of for loop for(django or raw queryset) for more than 1000 results

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, for-loop, optimization

I am not able to get more than 1000 results in ajax request(Server gets timed out for big data results). I wrote a simple query here

```
         query = '''SELECT l.id, l.timestamp,
                        m.dname, m.user_id FROM leaduser l
                        LEFT JOIN manager_detail m ON m.user_id=l.manager_id
                        LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT user_id AS log_id FROM 
                        lead_user_logs WHERE user_id=l.id ORDER BY 
                        TIMESTAMP ASC LIMIT 1) ll on TRUE '''
```

And now the for loop:

```
arr=[]
for lead in leads:
       new_dict = {
          'name': '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(lead.get_absolute_url(), lead.name),
          'phone': lead.phone,
          'manager': lead.dname,
         'clinic': lead.pname,
         'dietitian': lead.dname,
         'doj': localtime(lead.timestamp).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'),
         'time': localtime(lead.timestamp).strftime('%I:%M %p'),
         'sourcece': lead.source,
         'country': lead.address['Country'],
         'state': lead.address['State'],
         'city': lead.address['City'],}
        arr.append(new_dict)
```

I am not able to find what is wrong here(Loop is getting slow down when accessing to db columns)

Comment: You need to paginate your requests and add some indexes to your table to make select and other retrievals fast

Comment: yes i have already done the pagination. but what if i need 5000 results at a time